# What is the right way to package and to deploy QiMessaging Service application to Pepper/Nao robot?

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I'm confused about the right process of packaging and deploying a custom Service application to a robot. I'm using Python.

- I read [this document](https://www.arabicrobotics.com/Aldebaran/aldeb-doc-2.5.7.1/dev/tutos/create_a_new_service.html) but it looks more like a guide for App creation.
- At the other hand I tried [robot-jumpstarter](https://github.com/aldebaran/robot-jumpstarter) that looks very promising. I used `python jumpstart.py python-service my-package-name MyServiceName` command to generate a service template. I could open and install the Service trough a Choregraphe but I didn't find a CLI tool to do this. Moreover the project structure looks different from [this](https://www.arabicrobotics.com/Aldebaran/aldeb-doc-2.5.7.1/dev/tutos/create_a_new_service.html) and the `robot-jumpstarter` generates a lot of code. I want to start with something more simple and to complicate if necessary.

I would like to know what is the right `QiMessaging` service project structure and how to package and deploy to a robot with CLI tools. Now I'm loading the services with `autoload.ini`.

Edit: I found [this guide](https://github.com/aldebaran/qi-doc/blob/master/source/guide/qi-package-services.rst#id3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made robot-jumpstarter, and yes, it has a fair amount of boilerplate code to make debugging more easy etc.

If you want a bare-bones service, [How to write a qimessaging service](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/libqi/guide/py-service.html) in the documentation covers that; there's also [the tutorial you already found](https://www.arabicrobotics.com/Aldebaran/aldeb-doc-2.5.7.1/dev/tutos/create_a_new_service.html) that covers that and in addition also how to use qipkg, which is indeed the standard command-line way of packaging a service. The examples given in those two docs are indeed pretty much as simple as can get.

The minimum structure should be a manifest.xml, a .pml file, and your python script (and *maybe* an icon for the package; heavily recommended at least, apps without icons are ugly).

You should also be aware that:

- the word "service" can refer either to a *NAOqi service* (that registers, that you can call with qicli etc. and that is managed by the ServiceDirectory service), or to a *systemd service*, which is basically a standalone process (that may or may not contain a NAOqi service), that is managed by ALServiceManager
- often when one makes a NAOqi application in Python, the core code of the application is in one or several NAOqi services contained in the application's package ("application" and "service" are not mutually exclusive categories)